# Mahapps AppManager not changing theme

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I have a question regarding the ThemeManager class of MahApps.Metro.

I created a simple wpf application that has a MetroWindow as root element, and its working perfectly.

Now I am trying to change the theme/style of the application with a click on a button.

This is my code:

```
private void Button_OnClick (object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle (Application.Current,ThemeManager.Accents.First(acc=>acc.Name=="Red"),ThemeManager.AppThemes.Last());
}
```

I know its a bad practice to do it like that but its just a concept for what i am trying to do.

I put a breakpoint on that line and the debugger does reach it, but it does nothing :(

Con someone please help me?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You would probably be better off consulting the MahApps documentation (if there is any) for this problem. There might probably be a forum somewhere.

Comment: It works on my part, did you hook up your event correctly? Could you provide your XAML?

Comment: @gabrielle-harris please check, where your (MahApps) resources are located. If you put these in the MetroWindow changing the app style with Application.Current doesn't work. You should use `this` (your window instance) for the ThemeManager `ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle (this, xyz, xyz);`